# How to replace last occurrance of a specific character in field 1 using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to use awk to replace the last occurrence of a period in the first field with a semicolon. The field separator is also a semicolon.

I tested `(\.)(?!.*\1)` as a regex on regex101.com and it correctly highlights the last occurrence of a period when I supply "a.b.c.mp3" as input.

I have tried the following in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {gsub(/(\.)(?!.*\1)/, ";", $1)} 1'
```

It does not replace anything.

I would appreciate anyone that can help with this.

Comment: Share your regex101 link / give sample input, expected output

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a Perl-style (PCRE) lookahead assertion - AFAIK awk only supports Extended Regular Expressions (ERE). See [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Comment: Verifying a regexp on regex101.com or any other online site just proves it does what you expect on that site, you can't assume it'll work with any given command-line tool.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! The site that you link to does not support POSIX Regular Expressions but a few other dialects of regular expressions used in specific programming languages. This means that expressions that the site says do the right thing may not work as expected (or at all) with standard Unix tools like `sed`, `awk`, or `grep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, no implementation of awk supports PCRE lookarounds like `(?!re)`.

In GNU awk (aka gawk), using the [gensub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-gensub_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029-1) function, you could greedily capture everything before a period, and backsubstitute it in the replacement:

```
$ echo 'foo.bar.baz;something;else' | 
    gawk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=";"} {$1 = gensub(/(.*)\./,"\\1;","1",$1)} 1'
foo.bar;baz;something;else
```

Portably, you could instead use the [match](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-match_0028_0029-function) function, again with a greedy match, then pick out the substrings before and after the period:

```
$ echo 'foo.bar.baz;something;else' | 
    mawk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=";"} match($1,/.*\./){$1 = substr($1,1,RLENGTH-1) ";" substr($1,RLENGTH+1)} 1'
foo.bar;baz;something;else
```

With GNU awk you could (again non-portably) use `match` with capture and backsubstitution via its optional array argument:

```
$ echo 'foo.bar.baz;something;else' | 
    gawk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=";"} match($1,/(.*)\.(.*)/,a){$1 = a[1] ";" a[2]} 1'
foo.bar;baz;something;else
```

---

Since lookahead is perl-compatible, you could of course use perl (although perhaps without the capture of and backreference to `\.`, which in any case seems overkill):

```
$ echo 'foo.bar.baz;something;else' | 
    perl -F';' -pe '$_ = join ";", $F[0] =~ s/\.(?!.*\.)/;/r, @F[1..$#F]'
foo.bar;baz;something;else
```

[Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has awk-like `sub` and `gsub` that, like GNU awk's `gensub`, support captures and backreferences:

```
$ echo 'foo.bar.baz;something;else' | 
    mlr --nidx --fs ';' put '$1 = sub($1,"(.*)\.","\1;")'
foo.bar;baz;something;else
```

It doesn't currently support lookarounds so far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

How about `sed`? In your case, you are lucky to work on field 1:

```
sed 's/\.\([^.]*;\)/;\1/'
```

Comment: That assumes there's always at least one `.` in the first field. If not, something like `sed 's/^\([^;]*\)\.\([^.]*;\)/\1;\2/'` would be needed.